# Having trouble with Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

At first, I was coding every module/command in the same file, recently I separated them to `./commands/(modules).js` and trying to export these commands to `./index.js`.

index.js:

```js
        const Discord = require("discord.js");
        const client = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});
        const config = require("./config.json");

        const fs = require("fs");
        client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

        const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }

    client.on("message", async message => {
      if(message.author.bot) return;
      if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
      const time = new Date()
      const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
      const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

      if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

      const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

      if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type !== 'text') {
        return message.reply('Bu komutu özel mesaj aracılığıyla kullanamazsın!');
    }
      if (command.args && !args.length) {
            let reply = `Eksik komut girdiniz, ${message.author}!`;

            if (command.usage) {
                reply += `\nKullanım \`${config.prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
            }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
        }

      try {
        command.execute(message, args);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('komutu girerken bir hata oluştu!');
    });
```

commands/clear.js (for example)

```js
    const Discord = require("discord.js");

    module.exports = {
      name: "clear",
      usage: "<sayı>",
      guildOnly: true,
      description: "Sohbeti temizlemek için bir komut",
      execute(client, message, args) {
        if (message.deleteable) {
          message.delete();
        }
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Bu komutu kullanmak için yeterli yetkiniz yok.").then(message => message.delete(5000));
        if (isNaN(args[0]) || parseInt(args[0]) <- 0) return message.reply("Bir sayı girmeniz gerekli").then(message => message.delete(5000));
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Üzgünüm, bunu yapmak için yeterli yetkim yok.").then(message => message.delete(5000));
        let deleteAmount;
        if (parseInt(args[0]) > 100) {
          deleteAmount = 100;
        } else {
          deleteAmount = parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        message.channel.bulkDelete(deleteAmount, true)
       .then(async (deleted) => {
         const deleteMessage = await message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: **${deleted.size}** adet mesaj silindi.`);
         await setTimeout(() => deleteMessage.delete(), 5 * 1000);
        })}}
```

The bot starts without any issues, but when I run the command `!clear <any>` it giving me this error:

```js
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined
     at Object.execute (/app/commands/clear.js:12:25)
     at Client.client.on (/app/index.js:86:13)
     at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
     at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/daf7c446-62cc-4e90-99e4-775279447b67/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
     at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/daf7c446-62cc-4e90-99e4-775279447b67/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
     at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/daf7c446-62cc-4e90-99e4-775279447b67/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
     at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/daf7c446-62cc-4e90-99e4-775279447b67/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
     at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/daf7c446-62cc-4e90-99e4-775279447b67/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
     at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
     at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/daf7c446-62cc-4e90-99e4-775279447b67/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
```

Details:
Using: Glitch (free) for host and coding
Version: discord.js@11.6.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command.execute(message, args);` you only run the function with 2 arguments, message and args. However, you pass 3 arguments into the actual function (`execute(client, message, args) {`). So in this case, `client` is a `Message`, `message` is an `Array` and `args` is undefined.

One simple way of fixing this is by passing 2 arguments, the message and args, and removing the client.

So in your clear command file, it should be `execute(message, args) {` instead of `execute(client, message, args)`.

Hope i could help!